# Эфект наведения ссылок в блоке

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть блок материала новости который весь активен и клик на него должен перебрасывать на саму новость

По мимо этого в блоке есть ссылки на новость и другие элементы

Так вот, как можно сделать так, чтобы при наведении на блок все ссылки становились активными? А при наведении на другие элементы эта активность пропадала?

Вот пример, при наведении на блок ссылка становится активной, но надо сделать так, чтоб при наведении на кнопку эта активность пропадала

https://jsfiddle.net/xx9q1haa/

```css
a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
div.main {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div.main:hover a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <a href="">Ссылка</a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button>Кнопка</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

div.main {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.main:hover a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

div.main:hover .main-item-button:hover ~ .main-item-group-link a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main-item-button">
    <button>Кнопка</button>
  </div>
  <div class="main-item-group-link">
    <a href="">Ссылка</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А если структура сложней? Кнопки и ссылки вложены в n блоков которые могут менятся